# Need to read version from pom.properties in case when application is deployed as EAR or as war file

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, weblogic

When it is deployed as war (@Tomcat) path will be

- path 1> META-INF/maven/com.eg/testProject/pom.properties

and when deployed as EAR (@Weblogic) it would be

- path 2> META-INF/maven/com.eg/testProjectEAR/pom.properties

currently path1 is set as Constant in project so its not working in case of EAR Please suggest how this can be implemented so that it will work on both servers.

Comment: Has to be in a common place.  Change one or the other.

Comment: I would suggest to inject the values in the MANIFEST.MF file and read that...it's easier...

Comment: The META-INF directory of an EAR file is not accessible from applications because the EAR file itself is not part of the application class path.